# RegEx to extract Path and Filename from a Windows

Tags: regex, splunk

I have to write a RegEx to split a path and a filename from a full windows path, but I just dont get it...

What I have right now is:

```
(?<Path>.*)(?:\\+)(?:[^\\]*)\\(?<File>.*)$
```

My test path is: C:\ProgramFiles\CONEXANT\DTSCONFIG\setup64.exe

The Output looks like this

```
${Path} = C:\ProgramFiles\CONEXANT
${File} = setup64.exe
```

So for any reason the last directory of my path is not extracted.

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: We are using Splunk - and are testing on http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Which regex engine does Splunk use? (It is no help if regexstorm allows features that Splunk does not support,)

Comment: This should also work: `(?<Path>.:\\.*)\\(?<File>.*)$`. It won't include that last backslash. Because of the greedy match it will put everything before the last backslash into Path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have non-capturing groups in middle of RegEx which cause engine to match but not capture. Change it to:

```
(?<Path>.*\\(?:[^.]*$)?)(?<File>.*$)?
```

> Splunk regular expressions are PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular
>   Expressions) and use the PCRE C library.

Comment: Hi revo, thanks for the quick reply, there is one little issue left if I do just have a path the last folder is the file which is wrong - any idea for this? in the same step it would be amazing extract the file extension in the same step

Comment: What if last part is a file that has no extension?

Comment: Good question, but this is not possible in our case so that can be ignored

Comment: that is perfect - is it also possible to directly include an additional variable for the file extension?

Comment: Yes `(?<Path>.*\\(?:[^.]*$)?)(?<File>.*\.(?<Ext>.*)$)?`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your `File`

```
(?<File>[^\\]+\.\w+$)
```

And this should work for your `Path`

```
(?<Path>^.+\\)
```

Together...

```
(?<Path>^.+\\)(?<File>[^\\]+\.\w+$)
```

Output:

```
${Path}: C:\ProgramFiles\CONEXANT\DTSCONFIG\

${File}: setup64.exe
```